# Running a SQL query in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application where I have to subtract 2 time stamps and display the result on the webpage

I  have used the following sql statement and I am getting the results.

```
select (julianday(resolutions.created_at)-julianday(tickets.created_at))*24 from tickets,resolutions
```

the value of tickets.created_at is 2010-04-05 18:59:02 which is a time stamp and value of resolutions.created_at is 2010-04-08 08:10:33

Now where do I put this sql so that I can be seen in my webpage.
I tried it in the views page with the following but nothing showed up:

```
<% @sql = "select (julianday(resolutions.created_at)-julianday(tickets.created_at))*24 from tickets,resolutions" %>
<% @t=(ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(@sql)) %>
```

So how do I display it on my webpage?

when I perform the above I get the output printed on the webpage as

```
061.1919444389641(julianday(resolutions.created_at)-julianday(tickets.created_at))*2461.1919444389641
```

only 61.1919444389641 is supposed to be printed but the query statement is also getting printed.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your custom SQL in your model class, definitely **not** in the view.

Comment: my .rb file in the model folder just says:

class Resolution < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ticket
end

So I should add the SQL statement there? and how do I make it show up on the webpage view?

Sorry I'm a beginner in rails. I am not too sure about the internal functioning. 

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

In your controller

```
@tickets = Tickets.find(
  :all, 
  :joins => :resolution, 
  :select => '(julianday(resolutions.created_at)-julianday(tickets.created_at))*24 AS interval'
)
```

In your view

```
<% @tickets.each do |ticket|%>
  <%= ticket.interval %>
<% end %>
```

Generally you would put this logic in one of your models though, like this:

In your Tickets Model

```
def time_to_resolve
  resolution.created_at - created_at
end
```

To reduce the number of queries when iterating over multiple queries you would use this:

```
Tickets.find(:all, :include => :resolution)
```